# Android fragment show and hide

Tags: android, fragment

I tried to create a `ProgressFragment` to be used in the whole application:

```
public class ProgressFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY = "info";
    private CustomProgressView mProgress;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(...);
        mProgress = (CustomProgressView) root.findViewById(...);
        mProgress.start();
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mProgress.setText(getArguments().getString(KEY, ""));
        }
        return root;
    }

    public void setInformation(String text) {
        if (mProgress != null) {
            if (this.isHidden()) {
                show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
            }
            mProgress.setText(text);
        } else {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString(KEY, text);
            setArguments(b);
        }
    }

    public void hide(FragmentManager fm) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.hide(this);
        ft.commit();
    }
    private void show(FragmentManager fm) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.show(this);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

The `ProgressFragment` is expected to attached(added) to the activity once, and there should be only one instance, then the client should only update its' information or hide it.

Usage in client(activity):

```
class MainActivity...{
    ProgressFragment mFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFragment = ProgressFragment.newInstance(null);
        FragmentTransaction fs = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fs.add(id, mFragment);
        fs.commit();
    }

    //close the progress
    mFragment.hide()


    //show the progress 
    mFragment.setInformation("..")
}
```

However it does not worked as expected, sometime the progress view will show only at the first call or it does not even show.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Which class is `MFragment` ? Also, no `onCreateView` should be `@Nullable`.

Comment: Sorry I paste the wrong codes, I have fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't set your `onCreateView` as `@Nullable`;
- Use [commitAllowingStateLoss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss());
- Instead of just `add()`, use `addToBackStack()`. When you want to close it, just use the [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()) `popBackStack()`:

  ```
  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  ```

Comment: `show` is not exposed to the client, the only valid usage methods for the client are `hide` which is used to close the progress view and `setInformation` which is used to update the progress.